# Django - How to pass custom field value to database

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I've made a `ModelForm` that has all of `Student` model's fields and one extra choice field added in the form. But now that I have passed the choice field I want to know how I'll ever pass it to the database, because let's say for example that I want to pass the picked name as the name of the object on the database, how would I do that? This is how the FormView is like with only the model fields being applied:

```
class StudentDelete(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'students/student_form_delete.html'
    form_class = DeleteStudentForm
    success_url = '/'

def form_valid(self, form):

    form.save(commit=True)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

What would I need to do to add the choice field to the database in here (which is where I presume it goes)

```
def form_valid(self, form):

  #logic to add the field to the database

    form.save(commit=True)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here's the form, for reference:

```
class DeleteStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Student.objects.all(), required=True, help_text="Student Name")

class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: What do you mean with "add field to the database", what kind of field is choice in your db?,  is it defined in your model?,

Comment: Yeah, I probably should've added it. It's just a name field where you type in the name in the model. I want to choose one of those from the form (using the choice field) and basically modify it. I just need a simple example on how I'd do it.

Comment: If it's a model field then you just need to define a proper widget that replaces default CharField Widget with [SelectWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select). Just set widget for that field form Meta class ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)) and define your choices there.